openvpn-as (openvpn-acccess server) does not show admin web panel login info after remove & reinstall
I am using centos 7.
I removed previous installed openvpn-as like this :
yum remove -y openvpn-as openvpn-as-bundled-clients

after uninstall i installled it again like this :
yum -y install openvpn-as

The problem is during new installation openvpn-as does not show Admin login web panel address & it's password.
What is wrong about it and what did i do wrong to uninstall and reinstall again?
Here is the link for uninstall openvpn-as
It seems after uninstall it keeps previous admin web panel data and this is why does nor show it on new installation.
